# How to pass input parameter to jar file from java code?

Tags: java, spring, jar

I am creating a utility jar to fetch some data from database.This jar is added as a dependency in the web application.

Now to fetch the data from database I need to pass connection details to jar from my application say connection object or DataSource which application is using. So how can I pass connection details as input parameter to jar??

Flow:
From UI (some table/data selected) > Submit> will call abc method from jar with all FORM data> need to use connection/datasource of web application to fetch some data..!!

Comment: You have to mention about your jar file. In java you can call any public method of jar file. If you pass the parameter via method it is valid

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by calling jar's method and passing data source as an argument.